# What will be the solution to: $2^{\cos x}=|x| $Find $x$.

Tags: trigonometry

Well, the question is this really.

Find the solution to the eqn. $2^{\cos x}=|x| $

Can it done by plotting on the $\cos$ curve? If we square and take log on both sides, I think we get something similar to $\cos{x} = \log_2{x}$. So $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 2$ ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is this part of a bigger problem?

Comment: not really, no.

Comment: Note that both the cosine function and the absulute-value function are _even_ functions, so everytime you find a solution $x$, the number $-x$ will be a solution too. **Edit:** You are certainly right any solution must have $\frac12 \le |x| \le 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plot of your functions is

[image]

And you get simmetrical solutions for

$$
|x|\approx 1.24686 
$$

You can solve such problems easily as you mention or using Wolfram Alpha.

**EDIT**: the OP need to solve the equation without a plotting tool. In this case you could use the newton's method. It can be done manually and usually it converges quite quickly. You can check it here: [WIKIPEDIA LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

**EDIT2**: It follows the same plot using functions after having taken the log2 of both functions

[image]

Comment: Yup, Thanks ! Actually, I had been told to solve the problem *without* using any sort of plotting tools. Hence, I was wondering if there was an alternate way.

Comment: Ok then :-) Yes your method is ok but you need a calculator or computer to get an approximation anyway. Or you can plot the functions on paper without using software.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering, since cos x = log x base 2, can we take the 2 --> e and plot a cos x and a log x curve and determine the point of intersection?

Comment: Yes of course. But you are doing exactly the same as I did before. I will add the post to my original answer...

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the equation $2^{\cos x}=|x|$ is equivalent to $\cos x = \log_2|x|$, where $\log_2$ is the base-2 logarithm.

But if you want to "solve" (approximate) this by plotting graphs and, you might as well just plot $f(x)=2^{\cos x}$ and $g(x)=|x|$. I see Umberto did just that seconds after I posted this.

Comment: you mean f(x)=2^cos x?  hanks ! Actually, I had been told to solve the problem *without* using any sort of plotting tools. Hence, I was wondering if there was an alternate way.

Comment: @RishavMadcapRakshit What tools or methods for numerical solving have you learned? I think you are supposed to solve this by some numerical algorithm, then.

Comment: Nothing. I simply know basic trigonometry and their curves. However, ask me to plot 2^cos x manually, and I will have a problem...